# Timestamp formatting in Linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, timestamp

Is there a way to print formatted timestamps within the linux kernel? I have a proc file that displays a series of time related events, and I want to format the timestamps as date/time, honoring timezone, etc.

I have a struct timespec obtained via getnstimeofday(). I want to print the absolute date & time in the current time zone when I generate the content of the proc file.

Comment: What kind of formatting do you need to do?  seq_printf() uses a variable argument list and printf()-style formatting.  Not sure of any restrictions, but this works in my driver's proc handler: seq_printf(m, "count = %d\n", cnt);  You could do something more elaborate with a timestamp.

Comment: See the /proc/sched_debug handler for a timestamp implementation.

Comment: There is no *current time zone* inside the kernel. The time zone is a property of the user space. The kernel has no knowledge about it.